# How can I group a dataframe's observation 3 by 3?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggling with a dataframe of exchange-rate observations taken 3 times a day for approximately 30 days. This means that currently the dataframe is formed by 90 observations. For the purpose of my research I need to reduce the observations to 1 per day (30 observations), possibly by making the mean every 3 observations. In sum, I need a code that takes the observations 3 by 3 and outputs one observation every 3. I have tried some different codes but my attempts have all completely failed. I was wondering if someone had to do something similar and managed.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an example of your data in a way that can be readily copied, pasted and worked with by others. You could input your data frame into ```dput()``` and post the result, for instance. And please also post an example of the output you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group_by` and `summarise` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df=tibble(
  day = rep(1:30, each=3),
  rate = rnorm(90)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(mrate = mean(rate))
```

P.S.
Attach data. It will be easier to help out on specific data.